# How to use sum() function inside stored procedure in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

The example below works fine and it return some rows. But I need summary of the rows.

```
DECLARE
    x number;
Cursor c1 is
    select sal,deptno from emp;
    rw c1%rowtype;
BEGIN
    x:=0;
    open c1;
    LOOP
     fetch c1 into rw;
     FOR i IN 1..rw.deptno LOOP
       x:=x+rw.sal;
     end loop;
     exit when c1%notfound;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x);
    END LOOP;
    close c1;
END;
/
```

Suppose you have three employees and every employee's has different salary. The salary has due for 10 months and 20 months and 30 months. The salary is due for long time. So you want to add 2% bonus amount with salary for every month as the way:

The below description is for single Employee for 10 months:

Month-1 Salary = 800 =>  800*2%  = 16.00 => Total = 800+16 =816

Month-2 Salary = 816 =>   816*2%  = 16.32 => Total = 816+16.32 =832.32

............................................................................

Month-10 Salary = 956.07 =>  956.07*% = 19.12 => Total = 956.07+19.12 =975.20

The Months-1 Total Salary=816. So Month-2 Salary=816. This will continue up 10 months.Every Employee has the same condition. So I need summary of the total column. Thanks and best regards.

Comment: I think there is no need to use the inner for loop for your question if you want the sum of all the salaries  the outer loop is enough and will do the work for you.So just remove the for loop and use the`dbms_output.put_line` out side the main loop.

Comment: What is `NewCol`? You just changed your question, and it didn't become clearer. And the answer I gave to you is still actual. It doesn't matter how many columns you add. As many as you add to the select , add them to `group by`

Comment: "FOR i IN 1..10/20/30 LOOP" - is needed. The loop runs until the 10, 20, 30. Because the column Deptno has three different values such as 10, 20, 30. So your result and my result is not equal.

Comment: Look at my second answer

Answer (score 2):

When you use aggregate function `SUM` in your query (unlike, when you adding yourself), you don't need to convert `NULL`. SUM takes care of it. Although, as @DavidAldridge pointed, if you expect that all rows in summarized group of records may contain NULL, your sum will also be NULL. If you want to return a value, you can wrap your sum as follows `coalesce(sum(sal),0)`

This will give you SUM of all salaries

```
select SUM(sal) TotalSal from emp;
```

This will give you SUM by department

```
select SUM(sal) TotalDeptSal, deptno 
from emp
group by deptno;
```

In you question you posted that you need to execute it in stored procedure while your code as an anonymous block. If you want to return single value from Stored procedure you have a choice to declare function with return parameter or stored procedure with output parameter. To return a recordset from stored procedure in Oracle you need to declare a refcursor output parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_TotalSal_ByDept (
    p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN 
    OPEN p_recordset FOR
        select SUM(sal) TotalDeptSal, deptno 
        from emp
        group by deptno;
END;
```

**Edit**

I see that you added row - total. It is not changing much from the original question. Still, using cursor is not needed. You can run 2 queries and return 2 output parameters, one with data by department and another is total.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_SalByDept_WithTotal (
    p_total OUT NUMBER,
    p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN 
    select SUM(sal) INTO p_total from emp;

    OPEN p_recordset FOR
        select SUM(sal) TotalDeptSal, deptno 
        from emp
        group by deptno;
END;
```

Comment: "SUM(nvl(sal,0))" would be better as "coalesce(sum(sal),0)"

Comment: @DavidAldridge I tried to use same language our new user understands. In other words, emphasize on the question, not technique. In fact, when calling a `SUM`, no null-converting function is needed at all. Thanks for pointing

Comment: You'd just want the Coalesce if there were might be no rows with non-null values in, really.

Comment: @DavidAldridge This is true, true

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for? The Running totals?

```sql
SELECT totals.deptNo, totals.depttotal, SUM(totals.depttotal) OVER (ORDER BY totals.id)
FROM (
      select deptNo, deptTotal, rownum id
      from ( 
            select deptNo, sum(sal * deptNo) deptTotal
            from emp
            group by deptNo)
     ) totals
ORDER BY totals.id;
```

If you have some sort of department Id you can use that instead of artificially generated one from `ROWNUM`